# Max rx input voltage on FT232rl

Tags: usb, uart, ftdi, logic-level

The data sheet states:

"Integrated 3.3V level converter" on the UART and CBUS pins. (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/DS_FT232R.pdf).

I just want to confirm that means it's rx pin can accept 5v and will handle any level shifting internally automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not automagic.

You need to specify the "IO" voltage on the VCCIO pin. If you want to use 5V logic then you need to provide 5V to that pin. If you want to use 3.3V logic you must provide 3.3V to that pin.

That pin is basically the power to one side of the internal logic translator circuit.

> +1.8V to +5.25V supply to the UART Interface and CBUS group pins (1...3, 5, 6,
>   9...14, 22, 23). In USB bus powered designs connect this pin to 3V3OUT pin to
>   drive out at +3.3V levels, or connect to VCC to drive out at 5V CMOS level. This
>   pin can also be supplied with an external +1.8V to +2.8V supply in order to drive
>   outputs at lower levels. It should be noted that in this case this supply should
>   originate from the same source as the supply to VCC. This means that in bus
>   powered designs a regulator which is supplied by the +5V on the USB bus should
>   be used.

If you set it to 3.3V then try and provide 5V logic signals to it you risk breaking the chip.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense now. Also, later in the spec I saw max input as Vcc + 0.5v ... Glad I asked.